# How to judge the convexity of this function?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

$ f(X) = -\log \det(X^TX+I)$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is this function  convex or not? Does anybody have an idea about this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $f:\mathbb R^{n}\to \mathbb R$ is convex if and only if $g(t)=f(x+tv)$ is, for $x\in \text domf, v\in R^{n}$,

Comment: $X^TX$ is a symetric real matrix. Hence is it diagonizable to a matrix having a non negative diagonal with coefficients $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$. Hence $\det(X^TX+1)=(1+\lambda_1)\dots (1+\lambda_n)$. But I don't know what to conclude formally from there...